# Can't close webpack application with ctrl + C

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I configure my react app with webpack service, after running webpack, i found issues that the web server is still running on the local port, i tries ctrl + C may times but still doesn't work until i killed that port.

Here's my webpack.config file

```js
const { resolve } = require("path")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const TeserWebpackPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container
const isProduct = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

const config = {
    mode: isProduct ? 'production' : 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.tsx'
    },
    output: {
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".jsx"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "babel-loader",
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                    },
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin(
            {
                name: 'practice',
                filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
                exposes: {
                './practice': './src/App.tsx',
                },
            },
        ),
    ]

}
config.output.filename = "static/js/[name].js";

if (isProduct) {
    config.optimization = {
        minimizer: [new TeserWebpackPlugin()],
    }
}
else {
    config.devServer = {
        port: 3003,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
    }
}

module.exports = config
```

After i run it, it compile successful and deploy on localhost:3003, but after stop the service by Ctrl + C, and when I re-check the port, it still running.

[The command line say that my app compiled successfully, when I stop it, the port 3003 still work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FocbW.png)

Is there any attribute would force to kill the port after cancel or at least overwrite the port on the next compile, please help me

Here's my script I used to run the webpack app

```js
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "start": "serve dist",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```